# Simulating slow CPU with Windows7 XP Mode?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

I'd like to simulate a slow CPU, using XP mode in windows 7.  I can see settings for RAM, Drives etc, but can see any option for specifying processor resources.

Is there any way I can simulate older generation CPUs?

Comment: You won't be able to do this with XP Mode.  What is the purpose of doing this, perhaps there is another way, to determine what you are trying to do.  You can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928534/how-to-simulate-lower-cpu-processor-machines-for-browser-testing.  In order to actually use a virtual machine, and lower the cpu multiplier, it would require Hyper-V and hardware virtualization ( in order to determine if thats an option you have to tell us what CPU you have ).

Comment: It's for software testing. CPU is i5 2500k, which I think supports virtualisation.